# FATAL EXCEPTION : AsyncTask #1 using Google Maps api v2

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I get this error on the logcat:

```
03-07 19:03:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3201): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
03-07 19:03:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3201): Process: com.example.admin.tp1, PID: 3201
03-07 19:03:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3201): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
03-07 19:03:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3201):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
03-07 19:03:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3201):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
03-07 19:03:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3201):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
03-07 19:03:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3201):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
03-07 19:03:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3201):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
03-07 19:03:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3201):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
03-07 19:03:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3201):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
03-07 19:03:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3201):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
03-07 19:03:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3201): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: locationName == null
03-07 19:03:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3201):     at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocationName(Geocoder.java:171)
03-07 19:03:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3201):     at com.example.admin.tp1.MapActivity$MapTask.doInBackground(MapActivity.java:62)
03-07 19:03:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3201):     at com.example.admin.tp1.MapActivity$MapTask.doInBackground(MapActivity.java:51)
03-07 19:03:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3201):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
03-07 19:03:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3201):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
03-07 19:03:52.617: E/AndroidRuntime(3201):     ... 4 more
```

Here is my `AsyncTask` class :

```
private class MapTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {


        public double locLatitude;//Latitude du lieu à afficher sur la carte
        public double locLongitude;//Longitude du lieu à afficher sur la carte

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

            //On instancie le Geocoder
            Geocoder geoCoder=new Geocoder(MapActivity.this);

            try {
                //On accède à l'instance de la classe Address renvoyée par le Geocoder
                //et qui correpond au lieu à afficher
                Address locAddress = (geoCoder.getFromLocationName(adresse,1)).get(0);

                //mapTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                //On récupère la latitude et la longitude en attribut grâce aux getters de la classe Adress
                locLatitude = locAddress.getLatitude();
                locLongitude = locAddress.getLongitude();


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result){

            super.onPostExecute(result);

            //On récupère la Map en attribut grâce au getter de la classe MapFragment
             map = mapFrag.getMap();



            //On bouge la caméra de la Map vers le lieu à afficher
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(locLatitude,locLongitude)));

            //On fixe la valeur du zoom pour la map
            CameraUpdate zoom =  CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10);

            //On zoom ensuite sur le point
            map.animateCamera(zoom);
        }
    }
```

I execute the `AsyncTask` thread in the `onCreate()` method of the activity with:

```
 new MapTask().execute();
```

Can someone tell me how to fix it? I really don't understand where the problem is coming from.

Comment: What is the value of your adresse variable inside `doInBackground`?

Comment: the exception says "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: locationName == null" check the adresse value as antonio recommended, also check to see if getFromLocalLocation is not returning a null.